# i need to change a value of a 2d array thats not in the statement of my nested loop(nested loop is in a function)

Tags: javascript

a better explanation, is i have 2 arrays one that is listed in the statement of the nested loop and one that not and I'm trying to use the output or the middle of the nested loop to change but when i do this it doesn't change so i how would it change

```
function drawBricks() {                       // im using canvas and clear.rect so i have to be able to call on this over and over 
 for( i = 0; i < brickgrid.length; i++){    //brickgrid is my first 2d array 
    for( j = 0; j < brickgrid[i][j] ; j++){
       x = (i * 120)+60;               
       y = (brickgrid[i][j] * 40)+40;
      brickcentergrid[0].push(x);      //brickcentergrid is my second  2d array  witch is not changing when the code runs    
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.fillRect(x, y, 80, 20);       //the brick
      ctx.closePath();
  }   
 }
}
```

how would I change my code to allow the brickcentergrid to change or should I remake some of my code

this is my first post if you need some more info about my code ill post it in the comments

Comment: `j < brickgrid[i][j]` strange comparison. no length? btw, do you have a small set of data and the wanted result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have a wrong condition on your inner `for` loop

try to change it with this

```
function drawBricks() {                       // im using canvas and clear.rect so i have to be able to call on this over and over 
 for( i = 0; i < brickgrid.length; i++){    //brickgrid is my first 2d array 
    for( j = 0; j < brickgrid[i].length ; j++){
       x = (i * 120)+60;               
       y = (brickgrid[i][j] * 40)+40;
      brickcentergrid[0].push(x);      //brickcentergrid is my second  2d array  witch is not changing when the code runs    
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.fillRect(x, y, 80, 20);       //the brick
      ctx.closePath();
  }   
 }
}
```